# Changing comment title

Tags: comments

Drupal takes automaticaly first words of a comment like the title of the comment. Admin can modify a comment text, but there isn't apparently any place to change the title O_O!

How can I change the title of a comment?

Comment: Who wants to change the title? Admin, the user or programatically?